# Multiple id and one submit form

Tags: jquery

I have 2 pages with  same id elements.

If  I used id, first page comes from the values

```
var data = $("#FormData").serializeArray(); 

                    // output   
                   [0] name=    "FirstName";
                       value=   "George";                   

                   [1] name=    "LastName";
                       value=   "Anderson";
```

If  I used class , Comes values of all the pages.

```
var data = $("#FormData").serializeArray(); 

// output
               [0] name=    "FirstName";
                   value=   "George";


               [1] name=    "LastName";
                   value=   "Anderson";


               [2] name=    "FirstName";
                   value=   "Luis";


               [3] name=    "LastName";
                   value=   "Hamilton";      

                });
```

How can I get only  value of the second page?
thank you

second Partial Page

```
 <form   name="Ajaxform" id="FormData" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"  value="George" />
       <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName"     value="Anderson" />

        <button type="button" id="btn-success">Save Form</button>

</form>
```

first partial page

```
    <div id="MainPage">

       <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"   value="Luis" />
       <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName"     value="Hamilton" />

       <button type="button" id="ActionMenu">Insert Open Popup</button>

    </div>
```

index page

```
    <div id="MainPage"></div>

    <div id="PopupContent">
    </div>

<script>
            $("#ActionMenu").on("click", function () {

                // second page SecondPartialload

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Base/SecondPartial/",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: 'html',
                    async: false,
                    contentType: 'application/html',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#PopupContent').html(data)
                        $('#PopupContent').bPopup();  // popup 
                    }                                 
                });                                   
            });


             $("#btn-success").on("click", function (e) {

               var data = $("#FormData").serializeArray();               


            });

        </script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs on a page. Everything assumes that IDs are unique. Use classes if you need similar elements.

Comment: Why don't you just give them different IDs?

Comment: Because I'm doing to change the language. example <input <div id="LangCountry">Country Or other language Ülke</div> <div id="LangAddress">Address or other language Adres</div>

Comment: We're talking about the ID of the `<form>`. If you have multiple forms on a page, you should give them different IDs.